# Why does the command `pod install` or `pod update pod_name` install so many files?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I use firebase dynamic links in my react-native ios project.

`Cocoapods version --- 1.5.3 
xcode version --- 9.4.1`

When I tried to update the pod `Firebase/DynamicLinks`, using `pod update Firebase/DynamicLinks`, it updates not only that pod but so many others, most importantly it deprecates react to v0.11.0, and when I do git status, I see that the files added/modified are over 1100.

Also, the build fails with errors like `argument list too long`.

I can't figure out why this happens all the time with cocoapods.

I faced the same problem while installing segment-io to my react native project, so I had to manually link the project.

But firebase dynamic links is not a javascript library so there is no question of linking it manually.

Can anyone point to a solution?

Comment: Did You checked our answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like that because RN podspec is very old and not maintaned - Facebook doesn't use cocapods.

to fix it add this to Your target (in `Podfile`).

```
pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
pod 'Folly', :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"
pod 'glog', :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec"
pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', subspecs: [
  'Core',
  'CxxBridge',
  'RCTAnimation',
  'RCTActionSheet',
  'RCTImage',
  'RCTLinkingIOS',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTSettings',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTVibration',
  'RCTWebSocket',
  'RCTPushNotification',
  'RCTCameraRoll',
  'RCTSettings',
  'RCTBlob',
  'RCTGeolocation',
  'DevSupport'
]
pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
```

This will tell for cocoapods to use react native and other needed libraries from `node_nodules` - with versions defined in your `package.json`

And that script ad bottom of `Podfile` (after targets):

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React"
          target.remove_from_project
      end
  end
end
```

There are plans to improve that in future: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/pull/18

Comment: I use that code with latest react native version: `0.57.8`

Comment: don't forget to run `pod install` (and `pod update` if needed) after changes

Answer (score 1):

> When I tried to update the pod Firebase/DynamicLinks, using pod update
>   Firebase/DynamicLinks, it updates not only that pod but so many others
>   ...

Basically, this happens because `Firebase/DynamicLinks` *depends* on other repos (pods), which means in order to update `Firebase/DynamicLinks`, their dependencies should be also get updated.

As a suggestion, you should mention -manually- the latest suitable version for your project; In your `podfile`:

```
pod `Firebase/DynamicLinks`, 'here is the specific proper version'
```

Note that without mentioning the used version for the pod, it should install the latest, which could be *not* the suitable one in your case.